# React functional component with spread operator for props using typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

How can I use the spread operation to deconstruct the props that are passed down to a component? I have tried some ways to do it without any luck.

```
import React from 'react';
import "./button.component.css"



function ButtonComponent( {onClick: ()=> void, caption:string, ...otherProps}) {
    return (
        <button onClick={onClick} className="button" {...otherProps}>{caption}</button>
    );
};

export default ButtonComponent;
```

This is giving following error:

```
Binding element 'onClick' implicitly has an 'any' type.  TS7031

    4 | 
    5 | 
  > 6 | function ButtonComponent({onClick, caption, ...otherProps}) {
      |                           ^
    7 |     return (
    8 |         <button onClick={onClick} className="button" {...otherProps}>{caption}</button>
    9 |     );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can first declare an interface, then assign it as `type`:

```
interface Props {
  onClick: ()=> void;
  caption:string,
  otherProps: any
}
```

Then use it:

```
ButtonComponent( {onClick, caption , otherProps}: Props)
```

Or it can be used inline:

```
ButtonComponent( {onClick, caption , ...otherProps}: {onClick: ()=> void, caption:string, otherProps: any})
```

Comment: So, I can't mix the var declarations with their types as I did? I must always specify the descontruction variables and then their types? I swear I saw something more like the code I added. And I really prefer it. It is much compact.

Comment: You can do like this when you are receiving props without de-structuring, but not like this